# Assessing how a variable changes over time

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

I have a data set which includes the week number so 1,2,...,53 and then for each observation is a value for a variable, let's suppose it's distance travelled.

I'm looking for methods I can use to understand how this variable changes over this time period. So far I have grouped all observations into their respective weeks and plotted a line plot to gain a simple understanding of the mean distance travelled for each week. But I would like some stronger visualisations which can provide more information.

Comment: Depending on the variable it could be helpful to  group your data by seasons.

Comment: Do you have any additional data available?

Comment: And then what would you suggest after this grouping?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I can get a sample of the data but I believe the question is more to do with how you can visualise how a variable changes over time. In this case, 53 weeks.

Comment: You could look at total distance traveled over the time period (a cumulative plot).  You could look at the week-to-week difference in distance traveled, or the growth rate of the distance traveled over time.  You could look at a rolling mean value.  You could make a series of different means (a mean for every month) to see if you have some seasonality in your data.  You could check for serial correlation, to see if the distance you walked last week affects the distance you walk this week.  Going back to calculus, you could calculate the "velocity" and "acceleration" from any distance...

Comment: If an exploratory analysis is what you seek, you may want to first split the data between its overall trend and its seasonal component (see [here](https://mgimond.github.io/ES218/Week10a.html), for example). This should then help guide your analysis going forward . Note that "season" in your case could be defined by weekday/weekend or night/day and not necessarily by weather pattern.